# jquery Chat with PHP mySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, chat

I set myself a challenge today to write a jQuery chat in under half an hour.  It eventually took me 40 minutes.

However, I want to improve it so the load on the server and browser isnt horrendous.

Currently the user types into a text box, presses enter, this data is sent to a .php file which updates a mySQL table and outputs all the rows on the table.

There is a set Interval on the div every two seconds to update if anyone said anything without the user pressing enter.

I just wanted to know thoughts on how to do perform this in a better way, or the most efficient way.  I want to understand the best technology to use and why.

Thanks for all your input, I love stack overflow, its been invaluable to me.

Comment: Go and read up on Node.js and SignalR.

Comment: You could use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: That is what I am doing with .load()

Comment: @mdm do you have links to these, by any chance?

Comment: yeah i cant find a decent tutorial on it, I have no idea what I am reading.

Comment: This question has some links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729001/online-users-chat-like-on-facebook-with-nodejs-and-socket-io

Comment: and what if I cannot install node.js or something on the server side?

Comment: Then the first thing you can do is move to a none blocking distributed DB like Mongo or some other NoSQL alternative

Comment: Also make the chat only show the last 1000 messages, thats a scalable easy number to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Using ajax polling for a chat application with the "php back"/"javascript front" technology stack will inevitably result in a heavy server load. Http is just not designed for that kind of communication, and if you're using apache (as I assume) there is a really heavy overhead for each request.

As some of the commments indicated, you could investigate using a full stack javascript framework (i.e. [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) on the backend).

When I had the task of accelerating an existing chat application with php backend and Javascript frontend (using periodic ajax poll), I ended up using a 3rd party server side product to handle lightweight [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) requests. This server side product was [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/), but you could use [eJabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) for even better performance - OpenFire is easier to set up and maintain though. The results were more than satisfactory, server load dropped significantly, and messages were delivered instantly for ~1000 online users chatting wildly away (on a less-than-average performance dedicated linux box).

It's hard to explain all the tiny details within a SO answer's scope, but luckily Ben Werdmuller @ IBM went out of his way to write an [awesome tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-realtimeXMPPtut/) on this topic.

Comment: As a note: XMPP is actually what facebook use to do their chat, so maybe that's a sign of its scalability